# Firefox addon for viewing mysql

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, mysql

Is there ny Firefox addon for viewing mysql database same like sqlite manager for sqlite.I am using ubuntu any tool available for ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The common way to administer a MySQL using a web browser is to use [phpMyAdmin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin). Follow the link for a guide to install it and it's requirements.

Another tool (that I have no experience of) is [mysql-admin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/mysql-admin) it should be avaliable to install using the ubuntu package manager.